# python 3 make subsection for configparser

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert one open source project from Python 2  to Python 3 
Project uses configobj module which is not supported for Python 3.

Project uses subsections in config file.

How to realize similar functionality with configparser module?

e.q.
configfile.txt is:

```
[General Log]
filename = log.txt
[Thread1]
filename = thread1.txt
[[log]]
filename = thread1_log.txt
```

and with this config file i can do like

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
congfile = ConfigParser()
configfile.read('configfile.txt')

print(configfile['Thread1']['Log']['filename'])
```

should print thread1_log.txt

is it possible to make new class of configparser class to do this?
Any modules to support this functionality with ython 3

Comment: you may name your `[General Log]` as `[DEFAULT]` to get described result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/configparser.html#supported-ini-file-structure), `ConfigParser` only supports one section level, so unfortunately you can't do that using the `ConfigParser` library.

If you're using [this `configobj` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/configobj/5.0.6), it says it supports Python 3. Since you're porting the project from 2 to 3, you might consider upgrading to the new version of the `configobj` library at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. google transfers me to [old link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/configobj/4.7.2)