# How to read indentated sections with python configparser

Tags: python, configparser

I try to read the following config file with python configparser:

```
# test.conf
[section]
a = 0.3

        [subsection]
        b = 123
```

```py
# main.py

import configparser
conf = configparser.ConfigParser()
conf.read("./test.conf")
a = conf['section']['a']
print(a)
```

Output:

```
0.3

[subsection]
b = 123
```

If I remove the indents, a is read correctly.

How can I read a config file with indents correctly with python configparser?

According to the docs, it should work:
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/configparser.html#supported-ini-file-structure

I use python 3.7.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After raising a bug in python bug tracker, iI have found a way to read the indended subsections.
Add `empty_lines_in_values=False` to your code.

Bug tracker link: https://bugs.python.org/issue41379

```
import configparser
conf = configparser.ConfigParser(empty_lines_in_values=False)
conf.read("./test.conf")
a = conf['section']['a']
print(a)
```

Output:

```
hello
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But why the example works in the documentation is not very intuitive. I would rather not indent lines in config files in the future instead of having to think about this bool every time.

Answer (score 0):

Configparser supports only one section and no sub sections, if you want you can use config obj, http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html

check here, this might help you [python 3 make subsection for configparser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095280/python-3-make-subsection-for-configparser)

```
pip install configobj
```

and you should use double square bracket for a [[subsection]] like this in configobj module

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I know that configparser does not support subsections. I just wanted to use the indentation to structure the config file better. According to the documentation, this should also be possible.

Comment: according to documentation, it is possible, but this feature does not seem to be working, Probably we will raise a bug to configparser

Comment: Raised an issue for this, Hope this will be solved https://github.com/jaraco/configparser/issues/55

Comment: Thanks for opening an issue. Then I read the documentation correctly and it is really a bug in the configparser package.